# How to get the UTM zone of a shapefile polygon in geopandas

Tags: polygon, geopandas, utm

I need to get the UTM zone of the polygons from a shapefile. A piece of code:

```
all= gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shapefile)
for i,current in all.iterrows():
    UTM = ?
```

It could be, of course, the "projection string" in a way I can find it inside that using regex.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get the UTM zone. For iterating over individual shapes, the easiest is to use one of the python UTM modules, such a utm or pyutm. You can calculate the EPSG by prefizing the zone with 327 or 326, depending on which hemisphere the shape is in.

```
import utm

g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(...)
g = g.to_crs(4326)

for idx, row in g.iterrows():

    c = row.geometry.centroid
    
    utm_x, utm_y, band, zone = utm.from_latlon(c.y, c.x) 
    
    if c.y > 0: # Northern zone
        epsg = 32600 + band
    else:
        epsg = 32700 + band
    
    print(c, band, epsg, zone)
```

But you can also just sjoin to the UTM zones. If you have polygons, you'll probably want to join on the centroid.

```
url = 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b294795270aa4fb3bd25286bf09edc51_0.zip'
utm = gpd.read_file(url) 

gpd.sjoin(g.iloc[:10], utm[['ZONE', 'geometry']])
```

Answer (score -1):

The coordinate reference system info for your shapefile (if a valid .prj file is present), can be accessed via e.g., `all.crs`

Comment: Yes, indeed. However, I´ve a shapefile that has polygons spread in a huge area (Brazilian Amazon), and we are using UTM coordinates. So, we have polygons in different UTM zones, and I would like to know that "polygon-level" UTM zone.

Comment: coordinate reference systems are uniform for a given shapefile. If your data span multiple UTM zones, then you need to intersect your data with a layer than delineates those zones.